# PHP mail() Не приходят письма на почту

Tags: php, post, email

Сайт сделан на wp, не приходили клиенту письма при заказе.
Создал тестовый файл /send.php в корне, и там записал простейший вариант функции mail(), почты, указанные в коде, настоящие(код тестил на gmail.com и ukr.net).

```
$address = "test@gmail.com";
    $mes = "Test";
    $send = mail ($address,'Title',$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:orders@site.com");
    if ($send) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
```

При исполнении скрипта, никаких ошибок и предупреждений. Письма так и не доходили к почте, проверял в спаме. Перепробовал много вариантов кода, ничего не помогало. Затем я написал в саппорт хостинга, где мне ответили, что у них все норм и в логах чисто. 
Path to sendmail прописан: /usr/sbin/sendmail
Возможно у кого-то была такая ситуация?
Хостинг - freehost

Comment: Кратко: Настраивайте нормально почтовый сервер. Подробно. Скрипт правильный, нужно разбираться как настроен сервер. Вообще, какой хостинг покупали -- VPS или шаред? Что пишет при отправке на https://www.mail-tester.com/ -- доходит ли письмо?

Comment: @A K Виртуальный хостинг.
Никаких ошибок и предупреждений.
Письма не доходят,

Comment: Хм. Практический совет -- сразу в топку. Во-первых, вам самому не дадут крутить настройки postfix (DKIM и прочее). Во-вторых, почтовики ужасно не любят когда в обратной зоне не прописан сервер. Спам -- бич сегодняшнего дня, отсюда и все эти SPF и прочие драконовские правила. Я думаю на шареде самый толковый способ отправки почту -- только через phpmailer и аналоги, когда вы указываете гугловский аккаунт, через который отправляете почту (и когда упретёсь в лимиты по отправляемым письмам -- всё равно уползёте на VPS). Жизнь - боль, да.

Comment: Если всё ж хочется счастья много, всем, даром -- то ищите плагины по ключевому слову phpmailer, да вот например первый попавшийся: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/ принцип у них простой: не использовать локальный почтовик, а указывать параметры учёток от Gmail/Yandex и отправлять через SMTP этих почтовых служб. Способ для бедных, но работает.

Comment: Проблема в том, что плагин woocommerce юзает обычный mail()

Comment: Ну тогда мой совет -- в морг. Возможно в тему заглянет [KAGG Design](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220220/kagg-design) и что-нибудь подскажет, но я бы уже перешёл на VPS.

Comment: функция mail() на многих хостах уже блокируется, установите плагин Simple SMTP (насколько помню) , настройте и прибудет вам счастье.... :)

Comment: @ByArper здесь вы ошибаетесь, и очень сильно. Все приличные плагины, и WooCommerce тоже, используют только wp_mail(), а это две большие разницы)). wp_mail() использует phpmailer, что позволяет плагину подставить свой SMTP-сервер и отправлять через него.

Answer (score 3):

На шаред хостингах настройками почты рулите не вы сами, а ваш хостер -- и как он это сделает -- это лучше уточнять у него. И вообще, на шареде плохо - ни error_log не посмотреть, SSH и командная строка с драконовскими ограничениями.

Вторая проблема -- это почтовый спам, его огромный рост. Если раньше можно было на своём сервере за пару минут поднять открытый рилей -- то сейчас нужно выполнить кучу требований, начиная от PTR-записи, SPF, DKIM и много чего ещё.
Есть хостинги (типа mail.ru) на которых почта может даже до папки спам не добраться, а тихо умереть по дороге. (Ладно, gmail не из числа)

Поэтому на шаред хостинге ваша задача совершенно не простая. Пинайте хостера, меняйте хостера -- а лучше всё-таки идите на нормальный шаред. Я ладно помню времена десятилетней давности, но сейчас шаред стоит сущие копейки.

Альтернативно -- можно попробовать поставить плагины к wordpress, которые работают как PHPMailer -- умеют работать по протоколу SMTP и использовать учётные записи Gmail, Yandex и других почтовых служб. Впрочем, судя по вашему уточнению, что работа вашего плагина идёт через штатный mail() -- шансов не особо много.

Comment: Согласен со всем сказанным. SPF, DKIM, DMARC - без этого все будет лететь в спам, даже не доходя до вашей папки Спам. Настроить эти вещи на shared-хостинге не всегда просто. Поэтому совет ТС такой: ставьте плагин WP Mail SMTP by WPForms https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ , настраивайте отправку через SMTP (клиенты обычно используют бесплатную корпоративную почту Яндекс), и забудьте о всех проблемах. Плагин перехватывает обращения к phpmailer, поэтому любая отправка почты через wp_mail() будет работать через плагин.